# copy a section of data from stdin

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I am running a script that takes its input from stdin. This input can end up being very large so I want to extract the part I'm interested in to a temp file.

The first line contains "[cics]" and I want to write everything from that point until the next "[" to a temp file.

Never having really worked with stdin in scripts before I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is your question *"How do I read from stdin in a shell script?"* or *"How do I find a substring?"*.   There's plenty of answers to both already online, so if you don't already have something as a starting point, try to create one and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Please show us an example of your input, your desired output and the relevant section of your script. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this is going to be a bigger problem than I first thought. What I'm actually trying to do is replace a perl script but the problem appears to be that the script stays resident and is passed all incoming data by the calling program (it's a Xymon server side script if anyone knows Xymon). Thanks for the suggestions but it looks like I'll have to dig deeper on this one. Once I've got a bit closer I may come back and ask again.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[" } { if (index($0, "cics]") == 1) print; }'
```

To filter your input. It will not include the `[` characters.

I would suggest using the output of `awk` directly rather than using a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\[cics\]/,/\[/p' <<-END
    one
    two [cics]
    three
    four
    [five]
    six
    [seven]
    [cics] eight
    [nine]
    ten
    END
```

```
two [cics]
three
four
[five]
[cics] eight
[nine]
```